# How to fit a fixed-width table to the full width of a phone browser?

Tags: html, css

In an old web app, the layout was mostly done by fixed-width tables:

```
<div class="main">
    <table width="520" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>...</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Is there a way to fit the above fixed-width (520px) table to the width of a mobile phone browser window, when the page is first loaded?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this tag in your header and it should work

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no" />
```